# Jquery Getting correct element id with calling same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some different items on the same page and each of it has a comment part.My aim is to get input id when someone write something in textbox, but when i call textbox's id it return always same id,i mean it does not understand which input it is.

My codes;

***For Example***

***Item1***

```
<div id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >

            <div  class="form-group">
                <input type="text"  name="commentbox"  id="<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>" >

              </div>

    </div>
```

***Item2***

```
<div id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >

            <div  class="form-group">
                <input type="text"  name="commentbox"  id="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" >

              </div>

    </div>
```

Jquery;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[name = 'commentbox']").keypress(function (e) { if (e.which == 13) {
     var id=$("input[name = 'commentbox']").attr('id');
        ................
   return false;   
   }
    });  });
```

How can i understand which input have been pressed?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can get current element `id` using `this`

```
$("input[name = 'commentbox']").keypress(function (e){
    console.log(this.id); 
  //$(this)[0].id;
   //$(this).prop("id");      
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "$(this).id" ?

Comment: @Sasse  No you can use more way ..$(this)[0].id

Comment: or $(this).attr("id")